# How to use LibreOffice functions into Basic?

Tags: libreoffice, basic, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

I've [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30195024/good-usage-of-native-functions-in-libreoffice-basic) about the good way to do so.

Now I'm trying the following code [found here](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?p=54844&sid=03c9fbf9ce8e684bd1bccff488d38a09#54844), and get some unexpected errors.

I suppose I'm not using it the correct way. Any idea ?

```
Sub Main 
    Dim aResult 
    Dim aFunc 
    Dim oRange 

    aFunc = GetProcessServiceManager().createInstance("com.sun.star.sheet.FunctionAccess") 

    aResult = aFunc.callFunction("SUM", Array(1, 2, 3))
    ' ---- Works OK
    Print aResult 

    aResult = aFunc.callFunction("MDETERM", Array(2, 5, 8)) 
    ' ---- IllegalArgumentException
    Print aResult 

    oRange = ThisComponent.sheets(0).getcellrangebyname("B4:B6") 
    aResult = aFunc.callFunction("ZTEST", Array(oRange, 2.5, 1.0)) 
    ' ---- IllegalArgumentException
    Print aResult 
End Sub
```

Comment: Which "unexpected errors" do you get?

Comment: Those are IllegalArgumentException, as I mentioned in the code. They concern lines above the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MDETERM` needs a square array.

And `ZTEST` works only if there are values in the range.

```
Sub Main 

    Dim oFunc as Object
    Dim vResult as Variant
    Dim oRange as Object
    Dim bDoZTEST as Boolean
    Dim aSubArray as Variant
    Dim vValue as Variant

    oFunc = GetProcessServiceManager().createInstance("com.sun.star.sheet.FunctionAccess") 

    vResult = oFunc.callFunction("SUM", Array(1, 2, 3))
    Print vResult 

    vResult = oFunc.callFunction("MDETERM", Array(Array(Array(2, 5, 8), Array(1, 4, 3), Array(9, 7, 6)))) 
    Print vResult 

    oRange = ThisComponent.sheets(0).getCellRangeByName("B4:B6") 
    bDoZTEST = true
    vResult = Empty
    for each aSubArray in oRange.DataArray
     for each vValue in aSubArray
      if not isNumeric(vValue) then bDoZTEST = false
     next
    next
    if bDoZTEST then vResult = oFunc.callFunction("ZTEST", Array(oRange, 2.5, 1.0)) 
    Print vResult 

End Sub
```