# Call built-in IRR function in macro

Tags: libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

I am trying to call the IRR function from a LibreOffice basic macro, but get an

> Illegal Argument Exception

```
Function Bla() 
  Dim oFunc as Object
  oFunc = createunoservice("com.sun.star.sheet.FunctionAccess")

  Dim args(1) as Variant
  args(0) = Array(3300, -1000, -2000)
  args(1) = 0.1

  Dim vResult as Variant    
  vResult = oFunc.callFunction("IRR", args)
  Print vResult
End Function
```

What is the correct way to call the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, such functions expect a two-dimensional array.

```vb
Sub CallIRR() 
  Dim oFunc As Object
  oFunc = createUnoService("com.sun.star.sheet.FunctionAccess")

  Dim args(1) As Variant
  args(0) = Array(Array(3300, -1000, -2000))
  args(1) = 0.1

  Dim vResult As Variant    
  vResult = oFunc.callFunction("IRR", args)
  Print vResult
End Sub
```

To figure this out, I played around with the Java example at https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Function_Handling#Calculating_Function_Results.

**EDIT**:

A similar question is at [How to use LibreOffice functions into Basic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216466/how-to-use-libreoffice-functions-into-basic?rq=1)